# Form choices only from another entity

Tags: forms, symfony

I have an entity `Boite` which is related with another entity called `Category`. I have a getter like `$boite->getCategories()`. I have also a another entity called `Article` which is related to `Boite` too.

How can I change the `Article` form to only have the categories that I selected in the `Boite` entity?

I tried:

```
$form = $this->createForm(AdminArticleType::class, $article, ['categories' => $boite->getCategories()]);
```

to pass categories, but what should be next?

Comment: I think you are looking for [Symfony EntityType](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html) but I am not certain based on what you have provided. Good luck!